# Snapshot 18w02a: How do you set a custom name for an entity through commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have tried for a while now to set a custom name for an entity using snapshot 18w02a, but it won't allow it to spawn. the command is:
`/summon villager ~ ~1 ~-3 {NoAI:1b,Invulnerable:1b,Silent:1b,CustomName:"test",CustomNameVisible:1b,Team:"plr1",Proffesion:0,Career:1,Offers:{Recipes:[]}}`
When trying to use that all I get is a message that says Unable to summon entity. Does anyone know if maybe it is a formatting change that occurred or if the way you do custom names is different. I looked into the NBT after having tried for a while and found that the tag was still labeled `CustomName`. So I'm confused as to what has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to Fabian's answer: The CustomName in 18w02a no longer takes a string as argument, but a json text component. Your tag would look as follows:

```
CustomName:"{\"text\":\"test\"}"
```

For all details, I refer you to [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-java-edition/recent-updates-and-snapshots/2881545-18w01a-textcomponent-names) minecraft forum post.

Comment: I tried that, but without the back slashes. I will give that a try.

Comment: Interesting. How do you test for it now? Only with NBT?

Comment: Bäm, congrats to 1000 rep!

Comment: Works great! and no, you test for it the same way as before.
`/execute as @p at @s anchored eyes run teleport @e[type=villager,name=test,team=plr1] ^ ^-1.25 ^1.05`
You can also add color to the names with the extra tag `\"color\":\"color\"`. So this should make some things much easier to achieve now. The way to do everything feels kinda clunky, but I feel it is an overall great feature. The only way to do color and everything before was via external editing of nbt.

Comment: But how would you test for an entity that has a translatable text component in its name?

Comment: Just asked somewhere else and it's actually the language you set your game to. If you play on a dedicated server, it's always en_us. So you can now possibly break some adventure maps by changing your language setting. Wow.

Comment: Wow alright then... That is something that would need to be fixed.

Comment: My only question now, is that does the same principle apply to the `/give` command as well?

Comment: solved it: `/give @p diamond_sword{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"test\"}"}}` So they use the same style, but it is formatted just a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably isn't CustomName, it looks correct. But you wrote "Profession" with one F too much.

In cases like this, it's always good to write a shorter command first. If the shorter one works, add parts to it one by one, that way you see what part is problematic.

Comment: the problem is the `CustomName` tag. Without it, everything works just fine. Well, except for profession I guess.